# How to calculate inverse cumulative distribution using a table?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I need help with this:
$$P(X\geq a)=1-F_X(a)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{a-70}{8}\right)=0.25$$

When $X\sim N(70,64)$.

I know that it should be: $(a-70)/8 = 0.6745$

How do I get $0.6745$ From $Z$ table? I know that $0.75$ is between $0.67$ and $0.68$ in that table. Do I need to do an average $(0.67+0.68)/2$?

the final answer is $a = 75.396$

Comment: Please learn to format your post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

So I am assuming that the original question is 
$$P(X\geq a) = .75$$

So, I agree, a next good step is
$$1-P(X\leq a) = .75$$

This gives
$$P(X\leq a) = .25$$

Standardization gives
$$P\left(Z\leq \frac{a-70}{\sqrt{64}}\right) = .25$$

Then
$$\frac{a-70}{8} = \Phi^{-1}(.25)$$

To get $\Phi^{-1}(.25)$, it depends on the table that ***you*** have and what your instructor ***told you*** to do. I usually hear find the closest value.

Many tables are defined differently. Here is one I found online.
[image]
I looked for the closest value to $.25$ that I could find. I matched up the row and column and it gives me a z-score of $-.67$ (using a calculator gives $-0.6744898$).

So I have that
$$\frac{a-70}{8} = -.67$$

This gives $a = 64.64$, which is ***wrong*** according the the answer given. One possible correction is to consider that the original question is actually
$$P(X\leq a) = .75$$

By symmetry, $\Phi^{-1}(.25) = -.67$ implies $\Phi^{-1}(.75) = .67$ and so

$$\frac{a-70}{8} = .67$$
which gives $a = 75.36$

Comment: the original question is with 0.25 then I get 0.75 (by 1 - 0.25)

Comment: That is not what your post says. Please copy the problem correctly and learn to format your posts. It sounds like you are saying the original problem was $P(X\geq a) = .25$ which is **not** what you posted.

Comment: opps sorry! I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

My table, which may be very similar to yours, gives $\Pr(Z\le 0.67)\approx  0.7486$ and $\Pr(Z\le 0.68)\approx 0.7517$.

To get a better approximation to the $z$ such that $\Pr(Z\le z)=0.75$, we do a **linear interpolation**.

The number $0.7486$ is $0.0014$ short of $0.75$, while $0.7517$ is $0.0017$ above $0.75$. So a better estimate for the appropriate $z$ is 
$$0.67+\frac{0.0014}{0.0014+0.0017}(0.68-0.67).\tag{1}$$
A calculator shows that $\frac{0.0014}{0.0031}\approx 0.45$. Then using (1) we get the correction you quoted.

This linear interpolation is a kind of weighted averaging. Since $0.0014$ and $0.0017$ are fairly close to each other, the weighted averaging gives a result quite close to the simple averaging you suggested.

*Remark:* In the bad old days, when table use was common for many things, such interpolations were a standard feature in calculations.

Comment: @TalorT: You are welcome. The question takes me back, way back. In the not so good old days, I remember doing a Physics lab on a Friday and then spending half the weekend doing the calculations for the writeup.

Comment: I have another question: how do I calculate Φ(1.129) using table?

Comment: @TalorT: At $1.12$ the table gives $0.8686$. At $1.13$ it gives $0.8708$. Interpolating linearly, we get that the value should be about $0.8686+(9/10)(0.8708-0.8686)$. By the way, fine-grained results are often not worthwhile, since in real situations our random variable is only approximately normal, so a high precision answer may not be scientifically valid.

Comment: my teacher wrote a solution (without way) and he wrote that it equals to 0.9030??

Comment: I got 0.87058 before I asked you and the solution confusing me 0-0

Comment: Maybe it was to something other than the $1.129$ you asked about. Since $\Phi(1.13)\approx 0.8708$, it follows that $\Phi(1.129)$ must be (a little)  smaller than $0.8708$.

Comment: Your $0.87058$ (I would prefer $0.8706$) is very close to the truth. The reason I would prefer to give a four decimal place answer is that the data we start from in the table are only given to $4$ decimal places.

Comment: yeah he said write it close to 4 numbers after the 0.